# Comparison operator overloading in php

Tags: php

Is it possible to overload the ==/!= operators in php, similar to the way it's done in .NET?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Operator Overloading in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/787692/operator-overloading-in-php)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/787692/operator-overloading-in-php deals more specifically with overloading `[]`, not the equality/inequality operators.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

http://pecl.php.net/package/operator

see this as well:

http://webreflection.blogspot.com/2008/06/from-future-php-javascript-like-number.html

Answer (score 2):

Just for reference (as this identical question has been asked several times today), nikic has just posted details of a Comparable interface that overloads comparison operators for objects - https://github.com/nikic/comparable

Answer (score 0):

No, unfortunately you can't. You should create a class or member function.

Edit : oh, didn't know about this PECL package ! I should try it. :)