# compare class with int

Tags: php

I am using PHP Version 5.2.5.
I want to be able to compare my own class with int.

```
abstract class A {

private $value;

    public function __construct($value)
    {
         $this->value = $value;
    }

public function __toString()
{
        return $this->value;
}

}

class B extends A { }
```

but I want to be able to use my class like this:

```
$inst = new B(20);
if($inst==20) {
    //...
}
```

how I can do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Comparison operator overloading in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3111668/comparison-operator-overloading-in-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a [magic __toString()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring) method in your class.

```
class A 
{ 
    private $value; 

    public function __construct($value)
    {
        $this->value = $value;
    }
    public function __toString() 
    { 
        return (string) $this->value;
    } 

}

$inst = new A(20);  
if((string) $inst==20) {  
    //...  
}
```

Technically, __toString() must return a string rather than an integer, but PHP's loose typing will make the comparison using standard loose typing comparison rules

Comment: Doesn't work for me in PHP 5.2.12. When I return an int, it says `Method A::__toString() must return a string value`. When I force-cast the return value as string, the comparison doesn't work (not sure why). Also, it's worth noting that this apparently doesn't work at all in versions before 5.2

Comment: It will not work. PHP can't perform indirect casting. You need either `20` to be string, or `$inst` become string explicitly like that:
`((string)$inst == 20)` or `$inst == (string)20`

Comment: Sorry, yes! You need to explicitly cast to string both in the __toString() method, and in the comparison. Code example edited appropriately

Answer (score 1):

It's called operator overloading. 
Yes, you can do it. But you need to use the [PECL](http://pecl.php.net/package/operator) package 
(excerpt from description following:

> Operator overloading for: +, -, *, /, %, <<, >>, ., |, &, ^, ~, !, ++,
>   --,
>   +=, -=, *=, /=, %=, <<=, >>=, .=, |=, &=, ^=, ~=,
>   ==, !=, ===, !==, <, and <= operators.

)