# Is it possible to redefine operators in PHP?

Tags: php, object, operators, operator-overloading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Comparison operator overloading in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3111668/comparison-operator-overloading-in-php)

Can I redefine logical operators like "<", "<=" ... in objects in PHP? I know that you can make this in Java, C# or C++ but I don't know if this can be done in PHP

My idea is that I have a bounch of objects and I want to tell PHP that one object is less than other if his date attribute is smaller.

My principal alternative is to use the **usort** function, but I'd like to know if there is a more elegant way

Thanks

Comment: Java doesn't support *operator overloading* either.

Comment: http://pecl.php.net/package/operator

Answer (score 5):

No, PHP doesn't support operator overloading.

Comment: Yea, that's the term, Operator Overloading