# How to suppress the "Division by zero" error and set the result to null for the whole application?

Tags: php

How to suppress the "Division by zero" error and set the result to null **for the whole application**? By saying "for the whole application", I mean it is not for a single expression. Instead, whenever a "Division by zero" error occurs, the result is set to null automatically and no error will be thrown.

Comment: If you're looking for c++ operator overloading possibility, so the php doesn't support it, see the discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/787692/operator-overloading-in-php

Comment: Suppressing errors is generally considered a bad practice. You can use `try` and `catch`, but not `@`. You should write your code in such way that incorrect values are sanitized and no errors or warnings are thrown by standard execution of your code.

Comment: in `SQL Server`, there is a little trick `NULLIF()` http://www.bennadel.com/blog/984-using-nullif-to-prevent-divide-by-zero-errors-in-sql.htm

Comment: You could use a custom exception/error handler to catch it and set the result to 0 ... PHP 7 provides a 'DivisionByZeroError' exception class http://php.net/manual/en/class.divisionbyzeroerror.php ... in previous versions, it may be possible to convert the corresponding error to an exception and then set a handler.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This should do the trick.

```
$a = @(1/0); 
if(false === $a) {
  $a = null;
}
var_dump($a);
```

outputs

```
NULL
```

See the refs here [error controls](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php).

**EDIT**

```
function division($a, $b) {
    $c = @(a/b); 
    if($b === 0) {
      $c = null;
    }
    return $c;
}
```

In any place substitute `1/0` by the function call `division(1,0)`.

**EDIT - Without third variable**

```
function division($a, $b) {         
    if($b === 0)
      return null;

    return $a/$b;
}
```

Comment: Wow thats so simple (I wish I thought of it) but does it set it to null?

Comment: This is the best general concept. However, it fails when `a == 0`. You should change the conditional to be `if ($c === false)`. But actually, you should just check if `$b == 0`. ;)

Comment: Even though this is not exactly what I want, there might be not better solution.

Comment: You missed the $ sign function division(a,b) must be division($a,$b)

Comment: One-liner procedural: `$v = ( @($a/$b) ) ?: null;`. One-liner functional: `return ( $b === 0 ) ? null : $a/$b;`

Answer (score 5):

Simple as.. well **abc*123-pi**

```
$number = 23;
$div = 0;

//If it's not 0 then divide
if($div != 0)
  $result = $number/$div;//is set to number divided by x
}
//if it is zero than set it to null
else{
  $result = null;//is set to null
}
```

As a **function**

```
function mydivide($divisior, $div){
   if($div != 0)
     $result = $divisor/$div;//is set to number divided by x
   }
   //if it is zero than set it to null
   else{
     $result = null;//is set to null
   }
   return $result;
}
```

**Use** it **like this**

```
$number = mydivide(20,5)//equals four
```

I can't think of a way to **set it whenever there's division** but I'd use the function and **rename it** to something like ***"d"*** so it's short!

Answer (score 5):

This is a horrible solution, but thankfully, you won't use it because the variable is set to `false` instead of `null`.

```
function ignore_divide_by_zero($errno, $errstring)
{
  return ($errstring == 'Division by zero');
}

set_error_handler('ignore_divide_by_zero', E_WARNING);
```

In your case, I'd create a function that does your division for you.

Answer (score 2):

What about using a ternary operator, like so:

```
$a = $c ? $b/$c : null;
```

Comment: This doesn't really handle the 'whole application' aspect.