# php overwrite the = action of an instanced variable

Tags: php, oop, class, overwrite, type-safety

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Operator Overloading in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787692/operator-overloading-in-php)

I am trying to create a library that allows type-safe variables in php. I want to do the following:

```
class int extends typeClass{
     protected $value;

public function __construct($value){
    // Check if the parameter is a integer.
    if( ! is_int($value) ){
        throw new typeIntegerException('This isn\t an Integer.');
    }
    $this->value = $value;
}

// Returns the $value instead of the int class
public function __get(){
    return $this->value;
}

// Sets $value instead of the class
public function __set($value){
    if( ! is_int($value) ){
        throw new typeIntegerException('This isn\t an Integer.');
    }
    $this->value = $value;
}
}

$test = new int(5);
$test = "3";
```

Where $test = "3"; I want to call __set or a other method here instead of making $test "3". Is it possible to do that ?

Thanks in advance,

Greetings,
Bob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your closest option is the [`Spl Types`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.spl-types.php) library. The problem is that it is considered experimental and it may be deprecated. The boon is that it does exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: So the only way to get what I want is the use of an experimental class ? But if I get it right, it is possible because the Spl Types are the same as what I want to create. So how did they do it then ? Is there a way I can see the source code of there class ? Or is it in an other langauge then php? Still very thanks for the answer btw ^^

Comment: They did it in C and added it as an extension. I suppose you could fork the code and maintain it yourself if necessary.