# php overload = operator

Tags: php, oop, operator-overloading, overloading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Operator Overloading in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787692/operator-overloading-in-php)

Is there a way to overload the = operator ?

So want I is the following:

```
class b{
    function overloadis(){
       // do somethng
    }
}

$a = new b();
$a = 'c';
```

In the example above, I want that when $a = 'c'; is called, the method overloadis is called first and then that function desides if the action (assign 'c' to $a) is executed or aborted.

Is it possible to do this ?

Thnx in advance,
Bob

Comment: No, that post is about an array. I couldn't find the answer for a normal variable, not an array.

Comment: This strikes me as the wrong type of laziness.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No. PHP doesn't support operator overloading, with a few exceptions (as noted by @NikiC: "PHP supports overloading of some operators, like [], -> and (string) and also allows overloading some language constructs like foreach").

Comment: (there is a PECL extension for that, but it's just as good as nonexistent - it hasn't seen any development since **2006** and never moved out of beta)

Comment: -1 for the "not at all". PHP supports overloading of some operators, like `[]`, `->` and `(string)` and also allows overloading some language constructs like `foreach`.

Comment: @NikiC: Whoa. Never ever have I seen that for `[]`, either mentioned or in the wild - care to link to an example? I'm genuinely curious.

Comment: The `ArrayAccess` interface allows you to specify custom actions for array set / get / push / isset / unset: http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php

Comment: *[shudders]* PHP truly has a little bit of everything **and** the kitchen sink.

Answer (score 5):

You can imitate such a feature for class-properties, by using the [PHP-magic-function `__set()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#language.oop5.overloading.members) and setting the respective property to private/protected.

```
class MyClass
{
    private $a;
    
    public function __set($classProperty, $value)
    {
        if($classProperty == 'a')
        {
            // your overloadis()-logic here, e.g.
            // if($value instanceof SomeOtherClass)
            //     $this->$classProperty = $value;
        }
    }
}

$myClassInstance = new MyClass();
$myClassInstance->a = new SomeOtherClass();
$myClassInstance->a = 'c';
```

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the [PECL Operator overloading](http://pecl.php.net/package/operator) extension.

Comment: Although, as Piskvor states above, it's ancient, unloved, and not going to be overly useful.

Comment: at this moment, two betas was released on 2013, check it ;)

Comment: Couldn't get it to work with my local 64 bit Wamp on Windows 7.

Comment: Might need to adapting for 64-bit code then.