# Mathematical operations with classes PHP

Tags: php, oop

Is it possible to do mathematical operations with classes? For example I have a class called Term which stores a variable called coefficient; if I made two different instances of Term and did Term1 + Term2, I would like the coefficient variables to be added together and another Term class to be returned, is this possible?

Comment: Unfortunately, PHP does not support operator overloading. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7335765/php-overload-operator

Comment: This feature is pretty limited in PHP. C++ is an example of a programming language which gives you much more control when it comes to operator overloading. I would suggest you just give your class methods instead. like term1.add(term2)

Comment: http://www.techfounder.net/2008/07/08/operator-overloading-in-php/

Comment: There was an ancient PECL extension for overloading, and it looks like it's getting some recent development for PHP7 https://github.com/php/pecl-php-operator

Comment: Nope. Nothing stopping you from writing `public static function add(MyClass $a, MyClass $b)` though.

Comment: I am using add functions, I was just wondering if there was a more __sleek__ way of doing it