# Can I overload an array subscript operator in PHP?

Tags: php

I have a class with an internal array, and I'd like to overload the subscript operator to access the internal array and provide debug/logging actions.

Is there any possible way to overload the [] operator in PHP, or is there another option I should be chasing in this case?

Comment: duplicate of [Operator Overloading in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/787692/operator-overloading-in-php)

Comment: @JRL: That is the right question, but the accepted answer is really bad. Please don't dupe on it.

Comment: why do you call it subscript?

Comment: It's what is always been called in the languages that I've learned - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/th52k9c8(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, with the [`ArrayAccess`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) interface. Although you won't be able to cast the object to a proper array.

With [`ArrayObject`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php) ([as mentioned in the duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787692/operator-overloading-in-php/787747#787747)) you can however. Also see [this comment on php.net](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php#103508) on how to achieve this when you are extending `ArrayObject`.

Comment: I'll give you an upvote if you remove the part about ArrayObject. It's just the wrong approach.

Comment: @NikiC: hmmm, I've seen your comment on the other answer now; I hear what you are saying, but I don't necessarily agree with it. I think it depends on what functionality you are looking for. So I agree in part that caution is advised.

Comment: What would you suggest fireeyedboy? :) I like to see a few options before selecting if there are any others - though this one looks pretty good so far. :) +1.

Comment: @w00te: it really depends on the intended use. What do you want to achieve? Merely subscript overloading, or being able to iterate the object with `foreach()` as well, casting the object to proper `array` as well, etc.?

Comment: Actually I worked out how to use this - I just had to look at a few more examples.  Took me a minute to wrap my head around the ArrayAccess way of doing things - I'm too used to C-like languages :p Thanks!