# What is the name of the "[]" operator?

Tags: php, operators, terminology

The operator in question can be used for pushing values into arrays:

```
$array []= $value
```

The php.net article about [`array_push`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php) talks a few times about it, but it doesn't seem to mention its name.

Comment: That is the array subscript operator. You can see more about how to overload it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7586746/can-i-overload-an-array-subscript-operator-in-php)

Comment: ...or "square bracket syntax" : http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.array.php

Comment: lets call this NEW_ELEMENT_INLINE_OPERATOR ? but you can choose any name or title to call that structure :-)

Answer (score 2):

> What is the name of the “[]” operator?

There's no *special* name. The [PHP docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) simply call it *square bracket syntax*.

**Note:** It's not `$arr []=`, but `$arr[] =`. While PHP ignores whitespace, it shouldn't be confused with other shorthand assignments.

If you need to know what `$arr[] = ...` does, see [Flashin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18059430/164998).

Comment: Could you give an example of "other shorthand assignments"?

Comment: Sure. Things like `+=`, `-=`, `&=`, etc. While it may work, it's uncommon to write array assignment as `[]=`. That is, the square brackets are associated with the variable, not the `=`.

Answer (score 1):

You could consider this an array operator.. Don't know if there is an exact name for it though.

> Creating/modifying with square bracket syntax
> An existing array can be modified by explicitly setting values in it.
>
> This is done by assigning values to the array, specifying the key in brackets. The key can also be omitted, resulting in an empty pair of brackets ([]).
>
> ```
> $arr[key] = value;
> $arr[] = value;
> // key may be an integer or string
> // value may be any value of any type
> ```
>
> If $arr doesn't exist yet, it will be created, so this is also an alternative way to create an array. This practice is however discouraged because if $arr already contains some value (e.g. string from request variable) then this value will stay in the place and [] may actually stand for string access operator. It is always better to initialize variable by a direct assignment.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: The quote you have given doesn't seem to use the term (`array operator` that is).