# any way in PHP7+ to treat an object as an array via square brackets?

Tags: php, php-7

I see an interesting note in the PHP RFC forum that a `__toArray()` majic method is being proposed for objects in PHP 8.

My question is whether anything like this is possible:

```php
class SomeClass extends (maybe) ArrayObject {
    public function __construct($data) { ... }
}
$data = [
   'foo' => ['bar', 'baz'],
   'qux' => ['qaz', 'mem'],
];
$coolThing = new SomeClass($data);

// would output ['bar', 'baz']
print_r($coolThing['foo']);
```

without throwing an error

Comment: its possible since php5
https://www.php.net/manual/de/class.arrayaccess.php

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I overload an array subscript operator in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7586746/can-i-overload-an-array-subscript-operator-in-php)