# php array cut dimensions (return single 'row')

Tags: php, arrays, function, multidimensional-array

Is it possible to cut multiple dimensions in a php array?

**example**:
I want the 4th dimension of each first-level element

```
array(1) {
     [0]=> array(5) 
        { 
        [0]=> string(_) "/opt/path [10823] (/home/path/file.xml)" 
        [1]=> string(_) "/opt/path" 
        [2]=> string(_) "10823" 
        [3]=> string(_) "(/home/path/file.xml)" 
        [4]=> string(_) "/home/path/file.xml" 
        } 
    }
```

=>

```
array(1){ ( [0]=> string(_) "/home/path/file.xml") }
```

is there an internal php function or a way to achieve this without a loop?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/787692/operator-overloading-in-php

Comment: ok, nice link, but how would the specific function look like? Yes, I could overload the Array operator with additional functionality, but I want to know how to implement this functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [array_map](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.array-map.php) :

```
function selectMyLine($line) {
  return $line[4];
}

$result = array_map("selectMyLine", $data);
print_r($result);
```

You could alse do the same with [array_walk](http://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.array-walk.php), which directly edit your array instead of creating a new one.