# PHP static class Array[] operator?

Tags: php, class, static, overloading, operator-keyword

I need to implement the square brackets (array operator) in a static PHP class.

The main goal is to have class calls like this at the end :

```
MyStaticClass[ $something ] = $somethingElse ;
$SomeVar = MyStaticClass[ $something ] ;
```

I know that this is an heresy, but I really need it...

Any idea ?

I'm wondering if a static call to such an operator is possible, since I found nothing on the web.

Thanks for every help :)

Comment: The `[]` operator can't be overloaded in PHP, however you could use round brackets and [`__call()`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.call).

Comment: Okay, but what about extending Array ? -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/787692/operator-overloading-in-php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[]` can not be overloaded only variable and methods

Sample Class

```
class MyStaticClass
{
    static public $somthing = array("somthingElse"=>"Hello Benj") ;
}
```

Calling it directly

```
var_dump(MyStaticClass::$somthing["somthingElse"]);
```

You can also use

```
$MyStaticClass = MyStaticClass::$somthing ;
var_dump($MyStaticClass["somthingElse"]);
```

Both of them would Output

```
string 'Hello Benj' (length=10)
```

**In PHP 5.4**

```
function MyStaticClass()
{
    return MyStaticClass::$somthing ;
}

var_dump(MyStaticClass()["somthingElse"]);
```

Comment: OW YEAH ! Why didn't I think about that ? Many Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need to overload the operator.

If I understand your question, you want to be able to access and modify a field in MyStaticClass?

Then do this:

```
MyStaticClass::$something = $somethingElse ;
$SomeVar = MyStaticClass::$something ;
```

Just make sure your static properties are set to public in the class definition.

PHP doesn't really support operator overloading like C++ does:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php

[Is it possible to overload operators in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787692/operator-overloading-in-php)

Comment: I want to acces to an array, not a field (I know that stdClass properties are in reality an array). Baba's answer fulfills me perfectly, since I can derivate the inner static attribute from ArrayObject interface and make it do additional operations. Thanks for your post.