# overloadable operators in php

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Operator Overloading in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787692/operator-overloading-in-php)

I've found almost the same question answered "NO", but it was asked 7 months ago and new versions of php might have been supporting overloading.

Is there any way to overload comparing operators in php, like c/c++?
I have been developing a (sorted) list of objects for fast operation without iteration and I need to compare objects virtually, without knowing any properties on object. Comparison should be done with <, <=, ==, >=, > etc. Is it possible to define operators virtually or depending on any virtual comapring function(s).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/787692/operator-overloading-in-php

Comment: @Supericy OP asks if this has changed in the last 7 months; that question is from 2009.

Comment: @tomtheman5 Good point. But although not a duplicate, the answer is still the same.

Comment: Same question was also asked yesterday, and the answer was the same then as it is now as it was 7 months ago and 3 years ago

Answer (score 1):

No. This has not changed in newer versions.

Comment: So I have to go ahead in traditional php style. Thank you very much for replying.

Answer (score 1):

That'd be nice, wouldn't it?

But, no.

And I don't think it's in the works either (could be wrong on that though...). For now, it's best to use methods/functions with boolean return values: `myarray_lessthan($array1, $array2)`, `myarray_equals($array1, $array2)`, etc.