# Can I combine the Google Geocoding and Google Places APIs?

Tags: php, api, maps

I'm trying to make a PHP-based location search. I want it to be as 'smart' as possible, being able to **find both addresses and hotels, musea etc**.

Now I am currently using the **Google Geocoding API**, but the problem is that it can only seem to find addresses (when I input a hotel name it finds either nothing or some location on the other side of the planet).

I looked further and found the **Places API**, which can find all kinds of businesses and other locations. Problem is, I don't think (though correct me if I'm wrong) it can find normal adresses.

So my ideal situation would be being able to look for adresses AND other places at the same time. I would like to receive either a list of results sorted by **relevance** (determined by Google), or only the **most relevant** result.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Wouter Florign,

Your current problem has a few components:

```
  (1) the request/response from the Google Geocoding API
  (2) the request/response from the Google Places API
  (3) your workflow to process the responses/data from the above to API calls.
```

The main objective of your code is to maintain consistency between related and dependent objects without sacrificing code reusability (the continuation of your workflow is dependent upon your API responses). In order to ensure this, you should use the [Observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) to wait for your requests to complete in order to continue your workflow. The reason for using [the observer pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html) and not using [promises](https://github.com/reactphp/promise) is that PHP is almost completely single-threaded. Beacuse of this, an implementation with a promise will block your script until it is complete.

If you feel more comfortable using promises, you can have your [promise fork from the main script](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.pcntl-fork.php#98711), (using the PCNTL family of functions). This will allow your promise code to run in the background, while the main script continues. It makes active use of pcntl_fork, which allows you to fork a new thread. When the Promise completes, it comes back. It has drawbacks - the biggest of them being the inability to message the main process by anything but signals.

**Another caveat:**

I implemented something very similar to this a couple of years ago. I believe I ran into the same problem;

In my case, I was able to leverage the [Yelp API](http://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v2/search_api). This API is really fantastic]. All you have to do is perform a `GET` request on the Search API using the optional longitude, latitude parameter (it also has a radius parameter to limit your search). With this, I was able to get all kinds of information about businesses given the locations: hotels, restaurants, professional services [doctors, dentists, physical therapists]) and I was able to sort it based on various metrics (satisfactions, relevance, etc).

Please let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will look into implementing the observer pattern into my code. However, my problem is not making my code cleaner or faster at the moment. I know that's important but I'm not an expert on PHP and I think my current structure is sufficient for now.

I'm mainly looking for a way to combine the results of both Google APIs and take the most relevant one. I'm not sure if this is possible in some way as I haven't found anything mentioned about relevance in the API documentation.

I'll definately take a look at Yelp. It looks like it could be useful.

Comment: Wouter, I understand. If the main thing you're looking for is a way to combine your two results and have them sorted based on some soft criteria (in your case: relevancy), I would recommend looking at operator overloading in php (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/787692/operator-overloading-in-php). What you could do is translate your JSON response into a combined array of objects. Then you can have some criteria which defines relevancy (ex: distance from current location), then you can simply sort your objects based on this criteria.

Comment: Thus you will have `the results of both Google APIs and sorted based on  the most relevant one` Please let me know if you have any questions! (ran out of space on the above comment box =P)