# Is there an way to use Operator Overloading in PHP?

Tags: php, operator-overloading

Is there an way to use Operator Overloading in PHP?
I use PHP Version 7.1.

Comment: https://wiki.php.net/rfc/operator-overloading

Comment: There was an [RFC](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/operator-overloading) once.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to overload operators in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787692/is-it-possible-to-overload-operators-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well PHP doesn't support Operator Overloading altho I'd recommend looking at the thread bellow to read about possible similar solutions

[Is it possible to overload operators in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787692/is-it-possible-to-overload-operators-in-php)

But bare in mind, PHP's concept of overloading is no where similar  to C++